# How do I show the High Sierra upgrade setup assistant again?

Tags: high-sierra, upgrade, setup-assistant

I just updated to High Sierra, but managed to hang the setup assistant after install (I tried to open a URL). I force-rebooted the Mac, and the setup assistant was gone. How do I bring it back?

Removing `/var/db/.AppleSetupDone` brings back the initial setup assistant, but that's not what I'm looking for. I tried removing `/var/db/.AppleDiagnosticsSetupDone`, but nothing happened after I rebooted.

Comment: Try restarting and holding down the `Option` key. You may see an installed option as a disk. Select that one.

Comment: Wouldn't that just boot OS X normally?

Comment: If you were mid update it may boot to the installer and finish the update. I have only seen this once though so not sure if it will work in your scenario.

Comment: Huh. No, in my case, it seems the update finished completely. When I booted up again, it acted completely normally. I've been using it after that with no problems so far. (I ended up going to the initial setup assistant, making a temporary user account in the process and deleting it afterwards.)

Comment: Oh. I’m an idiot. I read question wrong. Disregard.