# How do I show the High Sierra application privacy dialogs again?

Tags: applications, high-sierra, upgrade, privacy

Background: see [my other question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/328271/251848).

I missed the new application privacy dialogs (e.g. in iTunes) the first time around after I upgraded to High Sierra. Is there any way to show them again?

I have tried restoring my iTunes preferences folder from a Time Machine backup before the upgrade, and then restoring my entire library folder (both from a second user account), but neither worked. Removing `/var/db/.AppleDiagnosticsSetupDone` and logging back in also did not work.